# Communicating with server with Backbone.js

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js

I'm a newbie web developer diving into Backbone for the first time.  One major question I've been grappling with (actually spending a lot of the last 2 days researching to no avail) is how exactly Backbone communicates with the server.

In my previous projects, I've been able to fetch data from my database using PHP and jQuery's `$.getJSON` method.  I'm also able to do this when I use Backbone (ex. `myCollection.url = "todos.php"`).  However, in every single tutorial, documentation, example code I've looked at, the url for the collection is always set as a directory and the urlRoot is directory/id (ex. `myCollection.url = "/todos"` and `myModel.urlRoot = "/todos/5"`.

My question is how exactly is this managed?  It seems a lot cleaner than the traditional way I was doing by adding GET parameters to my calls.  At first I thought this was routing, but that seems to be only related to setting browser history and stuff.  Some of the source code I've looked at uses SLIM PHP and Rails (neither of which  I've used) but I have no clue how any of the parts fit together.

Comment: Backbone expects a RESTful API to return JSON responses. Are you familiar with REST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backbone has its own api for communicating with server, such as fetch, save, destory.In fact, these methods do the same things with jQuery's $.ajax. For example, you use backbone's fetch in this way:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({     
    url : "rootURL/user",
});
var user = new UserModel;
user.fetch(
    data:{
        userId : 1,          //the webservice will be: rootURL/user?userId=1  GET;
    }
    success:function(model, response, options){
        //callback
    },
    error:function(model, response, options){
        //callback
    },
);
```

But you can also use the same way as in the jQuery to communicate with server in backbone's application.For example:

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        //do something
    }
    getUser: function(userId){     
        $.get("rootURL/user", 
             { userId : userId},
             success:function(data){
                 //callback
             }
          );
    }
});
```